# Hector pose estimation works, but only orientation and altitude is estimated

Tags: imu, hector-quadrotor

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am trying to use hector_pose_estimation package for a real quadcopter. I have published information from IMU, barometer using `sensor_msgs/Imu`, `hector_uav_msgs/Altimeter` and pressure height messages using `geometry_msgs/PointStamped` message (just like `hector_quadrotor` package does in simulator).

When I visualise pose estimate using `rviz` I see changes in orientation and height, but it doesn't move sideways, it's stuck in center and only height and orientation changes.

Am I missing something out or `hector_pose_estimation` package doesn't calculate movement on XY axes? Using this package with simulator works fine, but with my real data from sensors - pose stuck in center.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/154451/hector-pose-estimation-works,-but-only-orientation-and-altitude-is-estimated/) by [rock-ass](https://answers.ros.org/users/6716/rock-ass/) on ROS Answers with karma: 55 on 2014-04-17

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-04-17**:
Does you IMU data include accelerometer and gyroscope data, or only gyro data?

**Comment by [rock-ass](https://answers.ros.org/users/6716/rock-ass/) on 2014-04-17**:
IMU does include all data from acc and gyroscopes. Double checked data standard in sensor_data, also compared with data provided from gazebo simulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Finally figured out, pose estimation package requires gps `sensor_msgs/NavSatFix` data. Now I can get position (x, y) estimated.
Also I noticed some strange behavior - algorithm estimated that quadrotor is falling (estimated altitude was negative), because IMU sensor Z axis was -9,8. I had to invert IMU's Z axis value to get the algorithm stabilize quadcopter's altitude.

Hope this helps if someone encounter similar problem.

---

Originally posted by [rock-ass](https://answers.ros.org/users/6716/rock-ass/) with karma: 55 on 2014-04-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2014-05-01**:
If I'm not mistaken the IMU Z-axis is +ve if going downward.

**Comment by [rock-ass](https://answers.ros.org/users/6716/rock-ass/) on 2014-05-01**:
As far as I understand positive Z would be going down faster than gravity pulls you. But this time +10Z mean hover